How to send_goals to action server one after another
I have an action client and action server. I want the action client to send_goal to the action server one after another, that is only if the previous goal was successful. I'm not sure what kind of check to do on the action client side to force this. It sends all the goals at once and doesn't block until the future is available.
Two methods I have tried so far:

Following this idea: ROS answer for this

    for(const auto& goal : vec)
    {
        auto future = node->send_goal(goal);
        while (rclcpp::ok() && node->status != action_msgs::msg::GoalStatus::STATUS_SUCCEEDED ) 
        {
            executor.spin_some();
        }
    }

This sends the first goal and blocks, the goal succeeds but it errors before it can send the second goal
>>> [rcutils|error_handling.c:108] rcutils_set_error_state()
This error state is being overwritten:

  'rcl node's context is invalid, at ./src/rcl/node.c:446'

with this new error message:

  'the given context is not valid, either rcl_init() was not called or rcl_shutdown() was called., at ./src/rcl/wait.c:130'

rcutils_reset_error() should be called after error handling to avoid this.
<<<
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rclcpp::exceptions::RCLError'
  what():  failed to initialize wait set: the given context is not valid, either rcl_init() was not called or rcl_shutdown() was called., at ./src/rcl/wait.c:130
[ros2run]: Aborted


This method sends all the goals at once.

for(const auto& goal : vec)
{
    auto future = node->send_goal(goal);

    // Spin until the future is complete
    while (rclcpp::ok() && future.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)) != std::future_status::ready) {
        executor.spin_some();
    }

    try
    {
        auto result = future.get();
        if (result->get_status()== action_msgs::msg::GoalStatus::STATUS_SUCCEEDED)
        {
            RCLCPP_INFO(node->get_logger(), "%s executed successfully!", goal.c_str());
        }
        {
            RCLCPP_INFO(node->get_logger(), "%s failed", goal.c_str());
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        RCLCPP_ERROR(node->get_logger(), "Service call failed.");
    }
}

After some research, I believe that it is what spin_some() should do, and I was just confused. But I'm not sure how to proceed.
